# Using multiple if & elif statements in a while loop won't work

Tags: python

I have a task to make a program that asks the user about an issue they have with their mobile phone. My program is then to look at the input and go through a series of keywords it may recognise. Certain keywords allow it to read a certain line from a file I have created.

[Here is my code, it's fairly simple however isn't working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnco0.png)

I run the program, and when keywords are recognised from the if statement the program is supposed to print out the lines that match the keywords in the if statement. However if i put more than one keyword from different if statements it only prints out the line(solution) for the first keyword. I have tried using if instead of elif but this makes a bigger problem because the while loop doesn't break even when keywords are recognised.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] from your code, and don't use an image

Comment: Yeah it's kinda hard to help without seeing the file. As @MosesKoledoye said, please add more information to your question so we can try to help.

Comment: `eilf` is short for `else if` which basically means "if the above conditional didn't evaluate to true and this one does:" so of course it only does one, that is what `elif` does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question

First of all, as you have been asked in the comments, you should provide a MCV example, this means the smallest code that can run on its own and reproduces your error, which usually means including all in one single file but if you decide to keep the `.txt` at least provide it.

Also, paste your code, not an image of it, as we would need to retype all the code.

## Answer

If you want multiple prints you can't have them in the same `if ... elif ... else ...` block. You need to check each condition in its own `if ...` block. This modification means you don't have access to a common `else ...`, but this has a simple solution, check if the flag is still `False`.

```
while not keyword_recognition:
    if condition1:
        print("1")
        keyword_recognition = True

    if condition2:
        print("2")
        keyword_recognition = True

    if condition3:
        print("3")
        keyword_recognition = True

    ...

    if not keyword_recognition:
        print("Unrecognised keywords, ...")
```

## Further corrections

You have another bug:

```
<<< ('hello' and 'world') in 'hi world'
>>> True
```

First the inner of the parenthesis is evaluated, which yields "world" and then just this partial result is checked. If you want to force both to be in the sentence you should use the following:

```
<<< string = 'hi world'
<<< ('hello' in string and 'world' in string) or 'goodbye' in string
>>> False
```

The parethesis wrap both operations together, so string must either contain both 'hello' and 'world' or just contain 'goodbye'. Fullfilling both conditions would also yield True unless you use an exclusive or.

Answer (score 1):

It's because once an if or (elif) statement is matched the whole of statement is done. Use all if statements and get rid of your last else statement. If you never satisfy any of the if statements your false condition will remain false anyway. You can have your last if statement be if keyword_comparison == false print ('enter new key word') or something

Something like:

```
def myfun():
    boolean = False

    while boolean == False:
        word = input("enter input")
        if "hi" in word:
            print "test"
            boolean = True
        if "bye" in word:
            print "test1"
            boolean = True
        if boolean == False:
            print "please try again"
```